# $Y=UX$ with $U \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$ and $X \sim \gamma(n+1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, gamma-distribution

Let :

- $U \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$
- $X \sim \gamma(n+1)$ that is to say :

$X= \sum_{k=0}^n T_k$ with $(T_k)_k$ iid and follow an exponential distribution with parameter $1$

- $Y=UX$
- $U$ and $X$ independent.

We want to prove that : $f_Y(y)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{ y^k e^{-y} }{ k!}$ for $y >0$

---

My attempt :

$C= \ln(UX) = \ln U + \ln X$

$f_C(t)= \int_{ - \infty}^{\infty} e^{t-u} e^{u} f(e^u)  \mathbb{1}_ {u <0} du = e^t \int_{t}^{+ \infty} f(e^u) du$

$ f_Y(t) = \frac{1}{t} f_C( \ln t) = \int_{ \ln t}^ { \infty} f(e^u) du = \int_{t}^{\infty}f(u) du $

\begin{align*}
f_Y(t)
& = \int_{t t} ^{ \infty} f_X(x) dx   \\
&=   \int_{ t} ^{ \infty} \frac{1}{n !} e^{-x}x^n dx   \\
&= \frac{1}{n!}  \frac{1}{t} ( t ) ^n +  \int_{ t} ^{ \infty} \frac{1}{(n-1) !} e^{-x}x^{n-1} dx  \\
\end{align*}

Comment: it is not clear what you mean with $X\sim \gamma(n+1)$

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have edited my question.

Comment: Why ? $X \sim \gamma(n+1,1)$  in support in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and so $Y=UX$ in support in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ .

Comment: yes sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

$$\begin{cases}
y=ux\\
z=x
\end{cases}\rightarrow\begin{cases}
x=z\\
u=\frac{y}{z}
\end{cases}$$

The Jacobian is $|J|=\frac{1}{z}$ and thus

$$f_{YZ}(y,z)=\frac{1}{n!}z^{n-1}e^{-z}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(y)\mathbb{1}_{[y;\infty)}(z)$$

Thus

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{n!}\int_y^{\infty}z^{n-1}e^{-z}dz\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(y)$$

You can leave the density in this way or observing that

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{\Gamma(n,y)}{n!}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(y)$$

probably this expression can be expressed in what you are looking for...

---

Just as an example, with $n=3$ you get

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{6}\int_y^{\infty}z^2e^{-z}dz=\frac{e^{-y}}{6}[y^2+2y+2]\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(y)$$

which is a nice density

Comment: Thanks so much, I have found my error, and we obtain the same result.